# version 20.04.1 LTS, desktop kernel updates to a 5.8 version, laptop stays on the 5.4 chain -why?

Tags: kernel, updates

I have a desktop and a laptop machine, both of which run Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I regularly use the software updater. Until the 5th of this month both machines had kernel versions in sync, namely both updated to 5.4.0-59.

On the 7th the desktop updated to version 5.8.0-34, on the laptop the updater showed that
all was up to date and nothing needed doing.

Today (the 8th) the desktop has updated to 5.8.0-36, the laptop to 5.4.0-60. Thus the desktop is on the 5.8 chain and the laptop remains on the 5.4 chain. please can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Update schedules can be set within the "Software and Updates" application, with security updates applied on a different schedule to the others. Alternatively, one device may be following a different "track" than the other. Could you update your question to include the output of `uname -rv` from both machines?

Comment: I know about the schedules, both were in sync until the 5th Jan as they had the same schedules. The kernel versions that I posted were correct as returned bu uname -a on each machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is really confusing, but this is was always this way.

Obviously you installed Ubuntu to the desktop using the 20.04.1 iso image, that had `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` package installed. At that time iot was pointing o the same kernel as `linux-generic`. Both were `5.4`.

Recently `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` was upgraded in the repos and pulled the `5.8` kernel.

But you installed Ubuntu to the laptop using the `20.04` "pointless" iso. It never had `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` and it stayed on the 5.4 kernel.

You can easily change it either way if you want to have the same kernel version.

It is confusing a bit because both have `20.04.1` current version showing. But this is how HWE is supposed to work... Almost. This time thay made some mess with it.

Comment: The laptop upgraded automatically from 16.04, through 18.04 to 20.04 at the LTS date. The desktop had an ISO image from the Ubuntu site. I don't know what iot signifies other than "internet of things".

Comment: This is an expected behavior.